# Visual Studio Code not detecting java 17 installed even though java 17 was installed via a link gotten from vsc

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

So I recently installed OpenJDK 17 for Linux and it came to me as a tar.gz file. I installed it after clicking a link I got on vs code after installing a java extension pack (I had Java 11 installed by default, but I decided to get the latest version), under the adoptium's temurin tab of installing Java from vsc. So after doing so I reloaded the screen, but still no change. Vs code is still not detecting java 17 or 11 is installed. Also when I type `java --version` in the terminal, I get :

```
OpenJDK 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How do I make Java 17 the default version for VSC?

Answer (score 2):

You've added jDK11 to PATH, discard this configuration then **add jdk17 to PATH**.

Then turn to VS Code, open `User Settings.json` and add

```
"java.home": "<path to jdk17>",
```

Then reload window to make this change effective.

Comment: I got the issues rectified in a much simpler way:

I opened the software manager of my Linux mint and typed "JDK 17" I then downloaded all necessary JDK 17 packages then searched for "JDK 11" and deleted those. After this, I went to the terminal and typed "java --version" and it showed version 17. I then went to vsc and downloaded the extension "java run" and it worked. I did not watch any tutorials or anything. I just know that the software manager for Linux mint is like a superuser. It can access/delete and program-related files. So it was an easy fix.

Comment: @Command_Blocks. Glad your question has been resolved. You may write it down as an answer then accept it to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: nvm the java issue started again. I don't know what is happening with VSC. Like after I did the java I wanted to make sure my python projects were not harmed so I opened and ran them. "/bin/sh: 1: python: not found" error received.... I don't even have a folder called /bin/sh and I am 100% sure I don't have python, I use python 3.9.5. I did not change any python related settings. After that, I ran a java code to make sure my java was alright, but nope. It just gives an error. I guess I will just revert to pycharm and IntelliJ, at least those are easy to use.

Comment: and I can't seem to find the User Settings.json file... I opened it by mistake a while back and now I can't find it

Comment: I finally fixed it. After so many hours, I fixed it. Java is working. So is python. The run java extension messed up python directory or something, that is why python or java won't work. But I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps to fix the issue(I use Debian based Linux OS):

1. Went to my software manager, searched for JDK 11.
2. Deleted JDK 11 and installed JDK 17 from the software manager
3. Went to VSC and installed an extension "java run".
4. Ran the code and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In youre `settings.json` you can configure all youre jdk and use `default:true` with the one you prefer to use.
Example:

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
{
  "javadoc": "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api",
  "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
  "path": "C:/libs/jdk8u332",
  "sources": "C:/libs/jdk8u332/src.zip"
},
{
  "javadoc": "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api",
  "name": "JavaSE-11",
  "path": "C:/libs/jdk-11.0.15",
  "sources": "C:/libs/jdk-11.0.15/lib/src.zip"
},
{
  "default": true,
  "javadoc": "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api",
  "name": "JavaSE-17",
  "path": "C:/libs/jdk-17.0.7+7",
  "sources": "C:/libs/jdk-17.0.7+7/lib/src.zip"
}
```

],

But some specific extension need their own configuration. For example, sonar lint need this configuration:

```
"sonarlint.ls.javaHome": "C:/libs/jdk-17.0.7+7",
```